# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: “AIRMap” was not found in the UIManager. - react-native-map

Tags: react-native

1294/5000
I am a beginner in react-native and I have some difficulties in integrations related to Google. I've been having this problem for a few days now and I can't solve it. I added the react-native-map repository to my project, as I want to display a simple map for finding people nearby in my application. I followed the basic tutorial for installing the repository, I followed other tips on git for troubleshooting but nothing worked. Every time I run my application, the emulator displays the following message on the screen:

[image]

> [Fri Oct 30 2020 13: 22: 33.188] ERROR Invariant Violation:
> requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager.
>
> This error is located at: in AIRMap (at MapView.js: 994) in MapView
> (at App.js: 12) in App (at renderApplication.js: 45) in RCTView (at
> View.js: 34) in View (at AppContainer.js: 106) in RCTView (at View.js:
> 34) in View (at AppContainer.js: 132) in AppContainer (at
> renderApplication.js: 39)

Presenting this error on the console. I am using the following versions: `react: 16.13.1`, `react-native: "0.63.3`, `react-native-maps: 0.27.1` I am not able to execute even the basic test. I have already made the settings presented in different tutorials but nothing solved my problem. If anyone can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: Hello @Raquel Marina, 
You should share some code, therefore we can help to find that what is wrong. Also you should share with version RN and react-native-maps are you using.

Comment: I managed to solve it just by running all my code on the physical android. The error presented was related to the Emulator. 
Thank you for evaluating my question.